# Different Relative path inside External Js file

Tags: javascript, html

I have an Html file on 1 domain (let's say https://a.com) that calls a Javascript file on a different domain (let's call this https://b.com). One of the functions of the JS file is to load SVG files. The SVG files are hosted on domain b so the JS file uses a relative path to load the SVG file. The Issue I am finding is that since the HTML file is on domain A, the Javascript file is using the relative path from domain a.

Is it possible to change something in the html to have the JS file look at domain b instead of domain a? I do not have access to the JS file to do any modifications.
Here is how I am currently pulling the Js file

```
<script src="https://b.com/site/static/main-850382.js" async></script>
```

Below is the JS function for reference.

```
    function o(e, t) {
    for (var n = 0; n < t.length; n++) {
        var i = t[n];
        i.enumerable = i.enumerable || !1,
        i.configurable = !0,
        "value"in i && (i.writable = !0),
        Object.defineProperty(e, i.key, i)
    }
}
var a = function() {
    function e(t) {
        !function(e, t) {
            if (!(e instanceof t))
                throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")
        }(this, e);
        var n = t.dataset.name
          , i = "/site/static/svgs/".concat(n, ".svg")
          , r = t.dataset.svgTitle;
        n && e.renderSVG(i, t, r)
    }
    var t, n, i;
    return t = e,
    i = [{
        key: "renderSVG",
        value: function(e, t, n) {
            var i = new XMLHttpRequest;
            i.addEventListener("load", (function() {
                if (200 === i.status && (t.innerHTML = i.responseText,
                n)) {
                    var e = t.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0]
                      , r = e.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]
                      , o = Math.floor(1e3 * Math.random());
                    r ? (r.textContent = n,
                    r.id = o) : e.insertAdjacentHTML("afterBegin", '<title id="'.concat(o, '">').concat(n, "</title>")),
                    e.setAttribute("aria-labelledby", o)
                }
            }
            )),
            i.open("GET", e),
            i.send()
        }
    }],
    (n = null) && o(t.prototype, n),
    i && o(t, i),
    e
}();
t.default = a;
```

Comment: Not possible to fix that in your HTML or your end. The ideal solution would be to change the Javascript file as explained in the answer by stefantigro. You could also research if you can point to the other domain from your apache or njinx configuration, but I am almost sure that is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

'src' and 'href' are always relative by default. In your case if you want to pull an svg that is hosted in domain a from domain b you will need to do 2 things :

1. Make sure that the svg in domain a is basically a static resource or a resource your web server (nginx, apache, etc) will serve without any questions asked ( or your web framework will do the static serving... I can't tell because I don't know the specifics of your environment) https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/
2. You should use the whole path to domain b like so :  https://a.com/path/to/svg